# C strtok working if I try to print value but segmentation fault and null if I try to pass the value

Tags: c

```
void read_entries() {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(File_List[i], "r");
    char buff[1024];

    while (fgets(buff, 1024, fp) != NULL) {
      if (good_data(buff)) {
        count++;
      }

    }

    fclose(fp);
  }
}


int good_data(char* buff) {
      char *ip;
      ip = strtok (buff, " ");
      ip = strtok (NULL, " ");
      ip = strtok (NULL, " ");
      ip = strtok (ip, ":");

      printf("IP below\n");
      printf("%s\n", ip);
      //strcmp(ip, "69.12.26.238");
      return 0;
}
```

I have this function that's parsing a line and grabbing the ip out of it.  When I do the following it prints exactly as I expect.  But if I try to pass that ip to a function I get a segmentation fault.  Even by having a function below my printf line causes the printf to print null for the value of ip.  How is that possible? What can I do to be able to use the ip value?

Comment: It would be sensible if you showed a couple of sample lines of data (it might be "`word1 word2 machine.example.com 69.12.26.238:80`" or something similar).  Also, your `read_entries()` function depends on a number of global variables; you could improve the factorization of your code by splitting that up.  It would help make an MCVE ([MCVE]) simpler.  The `good_data()` function is using a global variable `ip` and not using the local variable `p`, which is puzzling too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the p thing is surely a typo.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: probably, but how did the copy'n'paste fail?  It's not a particularly good idea to show non-compiling code — I gave the charitable interpretation (it compiles because there's a global variable that makes it work), but neither an undefined global nor a typo is a good idea in a question on SO.

Comment: Oh *p was an error.  It should have been *ip.  I have no global variable ip.  I'm very new to C, read the C programming book about a week ago.  I'm used to higher level languages and dealing with arrays is a pain in C.  The examples I found for pushing things onto an array use global variables so that's how I set up that array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler agreed. I tend to paste the code I want analysed. I avoid to send it to the printer and re-type it in SO question widget. BTW would you agree that declaring a buffer of 1024 and reading 1024 bytes like done above does not guarantee null termination? I have an upvoted answer below I'm not too proud of because it doesn't solve the problem. So now I'm trying to deserve the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` returns a buffer that you have to use or duplicate at once which is bound to the first initialization buffer.

Fix it by making a copy like this just before returning it/passing it to a function (I have added more syntax checks BTW):

```
  char *ip,*ip_copy;
  ip = strtok (buff, " ");
  ip = strtok (NULL, " ");
  if (ip == NULL) return -1;
  ip = strtok (NULL, " ");
  if (ip == NULL) return -1;
  ip = strtok (ip, ":");
  if (ip == NULL) return -1;

  ip_copy = strdup(ip); // now you have a solid copy of the string, that has a global scope.
```

note: there are lot of similar errors due to the surprising way `strtok` works (not reentrant, with a memory effect).

Comment: @M.M; I had an horrible doubt: what I wrote in the first place was wrong. The original code works. It's just that you have to duplicate the last string returned by `strtok` or the value may be trashed when the original buffer goes out of scope / the values of the buffer are overwritten. I have heavily edited my answer. The question lacks a [mcve] maybe I should have refrained from answering that.

Comment: This is still causing a segmentation error as soon as you pass ip to strdup

Comment: I may have got carried away with strdup... can you printf ip just before calling `strdup`. Are your lines really long? because declaring a buffer of 1024 and reading 1024 bytes does not guarantee null termination.

Comment: printf prints the ip in the exact format I am attempting if strdup is not there.  However If strdup is there and the printf is above it, it prints (null)

Comment: @Steve there's a serious stack corruption problem somewhere. How long are your lines?

Comment: Lines are long: 2016-07-18T21:51:06.440147Z api-thing-com 69.12.26.238:54417 10.0.199.114:5001 0.000035 0.291514 0.000058 400 400 47 2 "POST https://adress:443/tokens HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2

Comment: works fine here. Can you create a [mcve] (test with a file containing only the line above) and see if it crashes. Then [edit] your question with that information.